# Crystal Reports - blocked ports on install to development machine?

Tags: crystal-reports, installation, port

I just purchased the latest version of SAP Crystal Reports and downloaded it from their site. I'm trying to run the Setup.exe program but as soon as I double-click it I get a fatal error message stating

"At least one port in the range of 4520-4539 must be open for the installation to proceed. Please ensure that no application or firewall is blocking this range."

OK -- well, I have a rule in Windows Defender that should be allowing those ports to be open, I've accessed my router and set the ports to be opened as well. But I still keep getting the message whenever I try to run the install. HELP!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got back an answer from SAP. The solution was to run the executable file by right-clicking it and selecting "Run as Administrator".